# StreamBuilder's snapshot doesn't have data despite sending it through Stream

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream, bloc

TL;DR: Values being added to `StreamSink` are for some unknown reason being overridden by the respected StreamBuilder's `initialValue`

From what it appears, my issue is similar to [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33515) issue on Github, but the only difference is that instead of getting a single value, I see two statements on the console log, one with the correct value which was added to the stream which was immediately followed by the initialValue which was passed to the stream builder.

In my case, I was using [generic_bloc_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/generic_bloc_provider)

---

Elaboration

I have a bloc [udhariBloc.dart](https://github.com/ashutoshsingh05/Udhari/blob/v3.0/lib/bloc/udhariBloc.dart)(line 99) which listens to a collection reference and adds the value to some sinks.

```
void _fetchUdhari() {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection("Users 3.0")
        .document("data")
        .collection("udhari")
        .where("participants", arrayContains: userBloc.phoneNumber)
        .where("firstPartyDeleted", isEqualTo: false)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {

//Initialized these to zero because their
//value must be recalculated upon every change.
//These variables were initialized to zero(their default value) when declared.
      _udhariList = List<UdhariClass>();
      _totalDebit = 0;
      _totalCredit = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.documents.length; i++) {
        _udhariList.add(UdhariClass.fromSnapshot(
          snapshot: snapshot.documents[i],
          userBloc: userBloc,
        ));
      }

      // Remove the udhari records where the participant is secondParty
      // and secondParty has already deleted the record
      _udhariList.removeWhere((UdhariClass udhari) {
        return ((udhari.partyType == PartyType.SecondParty) &&
            (udhari.secondPartyDeleted == true));
      });

      for (int i = 0; i < _udhariList.length; i++) {
        if (_udhariList[i].udhariType == Udhari.Borrowed) {
          _totalDebit += _udhariList[i].amount;
        } else {
          _totalCredit += _udhariList[i].amount;
        }
      }
//The correct values are calculated correctly, 
//printed and added to respective sinks as well
      print("Debit: $_totalDebit");
      print("Credit: $_totalCredit");
      print("List: ${_udhariList[0].context}");
      _totalDebitSink.add(_totalDebit);
      _totalCreditSink.add(_totalCredit);
      _udhariListSink.add(_udhariList);
    });
  }
```

and here are the streams and their controllers

```
/// Stream controller for displaying total debit on dashboard
  StreamController<double> _totalDebitController =
      StreamController<double>.broadcast();
  Stream<double> get totalDebitStream => _totalDebitController.stream;
  StreamSink<double> get _totalDebitSink => _totalDebitController.sink;

/// Stream controller for displaying list of udhari
  StreamController<List<UdhariClass>> _udhariListController =
      StreamController<List<UdhariClass>>.broadcast();
  Stream<List<UdhariClass>> get udhariListStream =>
      _udhariListController.stream;
  StreamSink<List<UdhariClass>> get _udhariListSink =>
      _udhariListController.sink;

/// Stream controller for displaying total credit on dashboard
  StreamController<double> _totalCreditController =
      StreamController<double>.broadcast();
  Stream<double> get totalCreditStream => _totalDebitController.stream;
  StreamSink<double> get _totalCreditSink => _totalDebitController.sink;
```

and this is my stream builder consuming the above streams

```
 StreamBuilder<double>(
   initialData: udhariBloc.getTotalDebit,
   stream: udhariBloc.totalDebitStream,
   builder: (BuildContext context,
       AsyncSnapshot<double> snapshot) {
     print(
         "============INSIDE DEBIT STREAM BLDR============");
     print("Conn State: ${snapshot.connectionState}");
     print("Has Data: ${snapshot.hasData}");
     print("Data: ${snapshot.data}");
     print("Has Error: ${snapshot.hasError}");
     print("Error: ${snapshot.error}\n\n");
     return Text("₹${snapshot.data.floor()}",
         style: _textStyleFooter);
   },
 ),
```

These sinks are then later consumed in a streamBuilders inside [Dashboard.dart](https://github.com/ashutoshsingh05/Udhari/blob/v3.0/lib/Screens/HomePageScreens/Dashboard.dart)(line 145). The problem is that even after adding data to respective sinks(in this case, `_totalDebitSink`), the values are not updated in the stream builder inside `Dashboard` class. For investigating further, I attached a listener to the `_totalDebitStream` inside the UdhariBloc's constructor

```
totalDebitStream.listen((onData) {
      print("CURRENT DEBIT: $onData");
    }, onError: (error) {
      print("Error listening Debit :$error");
    }, onDone: () {
      print("Done listening to Debit values");
    });
```

and every time there was a change in the value, I saw this log in the console.

```
CURRENT DEBIT: 100
CURRENT DEBIT: 0
============INSIDE DEBIT STREAM BLDR============
Conn State: ConnectionState.active
Has Data: true
Data: 0.0
Has Error: false
Error: null
```

Here, `100` was the updated value from Firestore and `0` was the initialValue which was provided to the StreamBuilder and also assigned to the variables `_totalDebit`, `_totalCredit`.

I used a similar technique in [dashboardBloc.dart](https://github.com/ashutoshsingh05/Udhari/blob/v3.0/lib/bloc/dashboardBloc.dart)(line 88) and [Dashboard.dart](https://github.com/ashutoshsingh05/Udhari/blob/v3.0/lib/Screens/HomePageScreens/Dashboard.dart)(line 212) and it works like a charm.

I haven't been able to find any solutions so far.

Comment: I tried to attach a listener in the build method in the consumer class (Dashboard.dart) and a saw a similar result i.e first the listener prints the correct value immediately followed by the default initialized value. There was no change

Comment: please see the updated code

Comment: `"Here, 100 was the updated value from Firestore and 0 was the initialValue which was provided to the StreamBuilder"` - what `StreamBuilder`? now for testing you are only using low-level `Stream.listen` so what `StreamBuilder` do you mean?

Comment: By initial value, I mean the variable `_totalDebit`'s value, which was initialized to zero.

Comment: No, instead I see 1 followed by 2 followed by 3 which in then follower by 0.

Comment: One clarification, I just discovered that the value coming out of the stream has no correlation with the default or the initialized value. Despite setting different values for initializing, I'm still getting an output of `0`

Comment: check `Stream<double> get totalCreditStream => _totalDebitController.stream;
  StreamSink<double> get _totalCreditSink => _totalDebitController.sink;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found the solution. Turns out it was a stupid fault on my part.
I accidentally mapped wrong streams and sinks to a wrong controller.
In this case,

```
Stream<double> get totalCreditStream => _totalDebitController.stream;
StreamSink<double> get _totalCreditSink => _totalDebitController.sink;
```

Here I accidentally mapped the `totalCredtiStream` with `debitController`'s stream.

Also, thanks to @pskink for pointing it out.